# Change in percentage between two different volumes

Tags: percentages

I need to show the progress of closed tickets between the 2 sprints in percentage difference.

Example:

```
Out of 150, I have closed 80 in 1st Quarter,
Out of 280, I have closed 167 in the 2nd Quarter.
```

Now, how can we find the change in progress in closed tickets as the Volume is different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

People love percentages, but it is hard to make them show what is important.  I would ask the person making the request what the purpose is to try to gauge what you should report.  If, as is often the case, you get no guidance, you just need to be careful to state what percentage you are calculating.  You could say we closed $108.75\%$ more tickets this quarter than last quarter.  That makes you look like a hero.  If that is accepted, I would work with the people who write the tickets to make more small ones.  You could say that last quarter we closed $53.33\%$ of the tickets while this quarter we closed $59.64\%$.  Now you didn't do much better because it obscures the increase in volume.  Maybe the tickets are different this quarter, either because you are at a different stage of the project or because the ticket writers have changed their behavior.  Maybe you closed so many more because you hired another person to help close them.  In any case, the arithmetic is easy but making a useful result is hard.  That is not a mathematical problem.

Comment: Thank you so much, Ross. This makes good sense. I appreciate your time to write such a long message with all scenarios. Good people like you still do exist to help others, not just answer to get upvotes. I'll convey this to my Management.